# F distribution function continious in $x\Leftrightarrow \mu(\partial (-\infty,x])=\mu(\left\{x\right\})=0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> > Consider $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mu)$ with $\mu$ probability measure. Let $F$ be the distribution function of $\mu$. Show that $F$ is continious in $x$ exactly then when
> >     $$
> > \mu(\partial (-\infty,x])=\mu(\left\{x\right\})=0.
> > $$

I do not know how to prove that.

For "$\Rightarrow$": Let $F$ be continious in $x$, then $\lim_n F(x_n)=F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$ for all sequences $(x_n)$ that converge to $x$. But now?

Comment: There is only one setting which can prevent $F$ to be continuous at $x$. What is it?

Comment: By definition $F$ is continious from right. So the only case that $F$ is not continious in x is that $F$ is not continious from left, i.e. $\lim_{t\uparrow x}F(t)\neq F(x)$.

Comment: Yes, and another property of $F$, besides being continuous from the right is that... Hence the limit from the left is actually always...

Comment: Its increasing, i.e. $\lim_{t\uparrow x}F(t)\leqslant F(x)$. Hence the only case when $F$ is not continious in x is that $\lim_{t\uparrow x}F(t)<F(x)$.

Comment: Indeed. And the difference between $F(x)$ and the limit from the left $F(x-)$ is the measure of the set...

Comment: $F(x)-F(x-)=\mu((-\infty,x])-\mu((-\infty,x-])=\mu([x-,x])$?

Comment: It is $\mu((x-,x])$?

Comment: Beware that $(-\infty,x-]$ and $[x-,x]$ are absurd, $F(x-)$ is just a notation for the limit from the left of $F$ at $x$. But $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$ and $F(x-\varepsilon)=\mu((-\infty,x-\varepsilon])$ hence $F(x)-F(x-\varepsilon)=$ ...

Comment: $F(x)-F(x-\varepsilon)=\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])$

Comment: Yes, and when $\varepsilon\to0+$, $\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])\to$ ...

Comment: Then $\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])\to \mu((x,x])=\mu(\emptyset)=0$

Comment: Noooo... :-) This is the crucial point and it is very good that we came to it: when $\varepsilon\to0+$, $\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])$ DOES NOT always converge to $0$, but to the measure of the intersection of the sets $(x-\varepsilon,x]$ (right?), which is NOT the empty set, but...

Comment: Oh shame on me, that is the continuity of the measure!!... set $A_{\varepsilon}:=(x-\varepsilon,x]$ then $A_{\varepsilon}\downarrow \left\{x\right\}$, so $\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])\to \mu(\left\{x\right\})$.

Comment: YESSS! Congratulations.

Comment: do not congratulate too early HEHE // now why is $\mu(\left\{x\right\})=0$ iff $F$ is continious in $x$?

Comment: Because we saw earlier that the very peculiar structure of $F$ makes that $F$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $F(x-)=F(x)$.

Comment: Then $\mu(x-\varepsilon,x])\to 0$?

Comment: Yes, $F(x-)=F(x)$ iff $\mu((x-\varepsilon,x])\to0$.

Comment: Sorry I do not see that. it is again $(x-\varepsilon,x]\downarrow\left\{x\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, $ F$ is non-decreasing and right continuous, hence continuity is sustained at $ x$ iff $F$ is left continuous at $x$, which means as $ \delta \rightarrow 0^+ $ you need to have $$ F(x-\delta) \rightarrow F(x) \Leftrightarrow F(x) = \sup_{\delta >0} F(x-\delta) = \sup_{\delta > 0} \mu((-\infty, x-\delta]) \\ =  \mu (\bigcup_{\delta>0} (-\infty, x-\delta]) = 
 \mu((-\infty, x)) = F(x) -\mu(\{x\}) $$
Hence clearly F is continuous at $x$ iff $ \mu(\{x\}) = 0 $